# Realtek ALC257 sound quality

Tags: drivers, sound, alsa, realtek, pipewire

I'm trying to install Kubuntu 23.10 on the Lenovo Yoga 11E 6th gen.
The problem I'm facing is the inferior sound quality compared to Windows 10.
The detected sound card is HDA Intel PCH with chip Realtek ALC257.

The overall quality of builtin speakers is not great (these are small and flat), but under Windows they are at least usable. Sound is relatively loud and distortion on high volume is rare. There is even a Dolby equalizer installed with the drivers.

On Linux, the volume is low. I raised the level of Master and PCM in alsamixer to 100%, but it is still too quiet. Comparing volumes on the same podcast on Youtube, I can barely understand, what the presenter is talking about. Also, with higher frequency tones, the sound is distorted.
Raising the volume level above 100% in KDE results in even more distortions. I tried to correct them with easyeffects, but it did not help too much.

Interestingly, in alsamixer, there is another device available "ThinkPad Console Audio Control", however it's not usable. When selecting it, alsamixer exits with message "cannot load mixer controls: Input/output error".

Update: I tried various ready to use presets for easyeffects:
https://github.com/JackHack96/EasyEffects-Presets
With the "LoudnessEqualizer" preset I got much clearer voice. Still, there is a quality gap comparing to what Windows offers.

Comment: Are you sure it is pulseaudio and not pipewire? If not care to switch? pipewire is the current default in Ubuntu and has a lot better hardware support than PA.

Comment: @Rinzwind Yes, my bad, it's pipewire. Corrected the tags.